# oracle procedure error while calling through getNamedQuery hibernate

Tags: oracle, hibernate, stored-procedures

i am getting following exception while calling procedure using hibernate

```
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.MappingException: Named query not known: loadUserByRank
    at org.hibernate.impl.AbstractSessionImpl.getNamedQuery(AbstractSessionImpl.java:70)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.getNamedQuery(SessionImpl.java:1260)
    at dto.TestHB.main(TestHB.java:22)
```

Here is the Oracle procedure:

```
create or replace procedure SELECT_USERS_BY_RANK
(
    OUT_RESULT out SYS_REFCURSOR,
    IN_RANK in int
) as
begin
    open OUT_RESULT for
    select
        u.user_id as user_id,
        u.name as name,
        u.rank as rank
    from
        AppUser u
    where
        u.rank >= IN_RANK;
end;
```

Mapping configuration code:

```
<sql-query name="loadUserByRank" callable="true">
    <return class="core.AppUser">
        <return-property name="id" column="USER_ID"/>
        <return-property name="name" column="NAME"/>
        <return-property name="rank" column="RANK"/>
    </return>
    { call SELECT_USERS_BY_RANK(?, :rank) }
</sql-query>
```

Executing code

```
Query query = session.getNamedQuery("selectAllEmployees_SP");
```

Comment: Do you have the relevent Oracle permissions to see/execute the stored procedure?

Comment: sorry for replying too late....yes i have the relevent permissions to see the stored procedure